# Implement product type in Scala with generic update function working on its parts

Tags: scala, typeclass

In Scala, I need to create a product type `&` that represents a compound value, e.g.:

```
val and: String & Int & User & ... = ???
```

I.e. `and` should have a `String` part and an `Int` part and a `User` parts inside. This is similar to Scala `with` keyword:

```
val and: String with Int with User with ... = ???
```

Having such product type I need a way to, having a function `A => A`, apply it to some product value and get that product back with `A` part altered. It implies that each type in product must be unique - that's acceptable.

One important limitation is that, when applying a function `A => A` to the product, I only know that the product has `A` somewhere inside but no information about other types it consists of. But as a caller of the function, I pass it a product with full type information and expect to get this full type back as part of function signature.

In pseudo-code:

```
def update[A, Rest](product: A & Rest, f: A => A): A & Rest
```

Using *Shapeless* or other esoteric stuff is okay for me. I tried using `HList`s but they are ordered, while something like heterogeneous set would be more appropriate here to represend `A & Rest` part.

**UPDATE**:

Here is the code that solves my use case taken from Régis Jean-Gilles answer below wit added read support, some comments, and improved type-safety:

```
object product {

  /** Product of `left` and `right` values. */
  case class &[L, R](left: L, right: R)

  implicit class AndPimp[L](val left: L) extends AnyVal {
    /** Make a product of `this` (as left) and `right`. */
    def &[R](right: R): L & R = new &(left, right)
  }

  /* Updater. */

  /** Product updater able to update value of type `A`. */
  trait ProductUpdater[P, A] {
    /** Update product value of type `A`.
      * @return updated product */
    def update(product: P, f: A ⇒ A): P
  }

  trait LowPriorityProductUpdater {
    /** Non-product value updater. */
    implicit def valueUpdater[A]: ProductUpdater[A, A] = new ProductUpdater[A, A] {
      override def update(product: A, f: A ⇒ A): A = f(product)
    }
  }

  object ProductUpdater extends LowPriorityProductUpdater {
    /** Left-biased product value updater. */
    implicit def leftProductUpdater[L, R, A](implicit leftUpdater: ProductUpdater[L, A]): ProductUpdater[L & R, A] =
      new ProductUpdater[L & R, A] {
        override def update(product: L & R, f: A ⇒ A): L & R =
          leftUpdater.update(product.left, f) & product.right
      }

    /** Right-biased product value updater. */
    implicit def rightProductUpdater[L, R, A](implicit rightUpdater: ProductUpdater[R, A]): ProductUpdater[L & R, A] =
      new ProductUpdater[L & R, A] {
        override def update(product: L & R, f: A ⇒ A): L & R =
          product.left & rightUpdater.update(product.right, f)
      }
  }

  /** Update product value of type `A` with function `f`.
    * Won't compile if product contains multiple `A` values.
    * @return updated product */
  def update[P, A](product: P)(f: A ⇒ A)(implicit updater: ProductUpdater[P, A]): P =
    updater.update(product, f)

  /* Reader. */

  /** Product reader able to read value of type `A`. */
  trait ProductReader[P, A] {
    /** Read product value of type `A`. */
    def read(product: P): A
  }

  trait LowPriorityProductReader {
    /** Non-product value reader. */
    implicit def valueReader[A]: ProductReader[A, A] = new ProductReader[A, A] {
      override def read(product: A): A = product
    }
  }

  object ProductReader extends LowPriorityProductReader {
    /** Left-biased product value reader. */
    implicit def leftProductReader[L, R, A](implicit leftReader: ProductReader[L, A]): ProductReader[L & R, A] =
      new ProductReader[L & R, A] {
        override def read(product: L & R): A =
          leftReader.read(product.left)
      }

    /** Right-biased product value reader. */
    implicit def rightProductReader[L, R, A](implicit rightReader: ProductReader[R, A]): ProductReader[L & R, A] =
      new ProductReader[L & R, A] {
        override def read(product: L & R): A =
          rightReader.read(product.right)
      }
  }

  /** Read product value of type `A`.
    * Won't compile if product contains multiple `A` values.
    * @return value of type `A` */
  def read[P, A](product: P)(implicit productReader: ProductReader[P, A]): A =
    productReader.read(product)

  // let's test it

  val p = 1 & 2.0 & "three"

  read[Int & Double & String, Int](p) // 1
  read[Int & Double & String, Double](p) // 2.0
  read[Int & Double & String, String](p) // three

  update[Int & Double & String, Int](p)(_ * 2) // 2 & 2.0 & three
  update[Int & Double & String, Double](p)(_ * 2) // 1 & 4.0 & three
  update[Int & Double & String, String](p)(_ * 2) // 1 & 2.0 & threethree

}
```

Comment: About `HList` being ordered: this can't be fixed, ever. While you can define methods/type classes that will compare two products and tell you if they have the same type irrespective of the ordering, when it comes to the type system per se you are out of luck. You can try every magic, you'll never be able to have the compiler think that `&[Int, String]` is the same as `&[String, Int]` (short of implementing a compiler plugin that would entirely take over the type checking for those types, if that's even possible).

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles, got it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using only pure scala with no required library. It relies on a type class using a rather standard approach:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
case class &[L,R](left: L, right: R)
implicit class AndOp[L](val left: L) {
  def &[R](right: R): L & R = new &(left, right)
}

trait ProductUpdater[P,A] {
  def apply(p: P, f: A => A): P
}
trait LowPriorityProductUpdater {
  implicit def noopValueUpdater[P,A]: ProductUpdater[P,A] = {
    new ProductUpdater[P,A] {
      def apply(p: P, f: A => A): P = p // keep as is
    }
  }
}
object ProductUpdater extends LowPriorityProductUpdater {
  implicit def simpleValueUpdater[A]: ProductUpdater[A,A] = {
    new ProductUpdater[A,A] {
      def apply(p: A, f: A => A): A = f(p)
    }
  }
  implicit def productUpdater[L, R, A](
    implicit leftUpdater: ProductUpdater[L, A], rightUpdater: ProductUpdater[R, A]
  ): ProductUpdater[L & R, A] = {
    new ProductUpdater[L & R, A] {
      def apply(p: L & R, f: A => A): L & R = &(leftUpdater(p.left, f), rightUpdater(p.right, f))
    }
  }
}
def update[A,P](product: P)(f: A => A)(implicit updater: ProductUpdater[P,A]): P = updater(product, f)
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
```

Let's test it:

```
scala> case class User(name: String, age: Int)
defined class User

scala> val p: String & Int & User & String = "hello" & 123 & User("Elwood", 25) & "bye"
p: &[&[&[String,Int],User],String] = &(&(&(hello,123),User(Elwood,25)),bye)

scala> update(p){ i: Int => i + 1 }
res0: &[&[&[String,Int],User],String] = &(&(&(hello,124),User(Elwood,25)),bye)

scala> update(p){ s: String => s.toUpperCase }
res1: &[&[&[String,Int],User],String] = &(&(&(HELLO,123),User(Elwood,25)),BYE)

scala> update(p){ user: User =>
     |   user.copy(name = user.name.toUpperCase, age = user.age*2)
     | }
res2: &[&[&[String,Int],User],String] = &(&(&(hello,123),User(ELWOOD,50)),bye)
```

---

**Update:** In response to:

> Is it possible to make this not compile when a product doesn't contain a value to update

Yes it is most definitely possible. We could alter the `ProductUpdater`type class but in this case I find it much easier to introduce a separate type class `ProductContainsType` as an evidence that a given product `P` contains at least one element of type `A`:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

@annotation.implicitNotFound("Product ${P} does not contain type ${A}")
abstract sealed class ProductContainsType[P,A]
trait LowPriorityProductContainsType {
  implicit def compositeProductContainsTypeInRightPart[L, R, A](
    implicit rightContainsType: ProductContainsType[R, A]
  ): ProductContainsType[L & R, A] = null
}
object ProductContainsType extends LowPriorityProductContainsType {
  implicit def simpleProductContainsType[A]: ProductContainsType[A,A] = null
  implicit def compositeProductContainsTypeInLeftPart[L, R, A](
    implicit leftContainsType: ProductContainsType[L, A]
  ): ProductContainsType[L & R, A] = null
}
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
```

Now we can define our stricter `update` method:

```
def strictUpdate[A,P](product: P)(f: A => A)(
  implicit 
    updater: ProductUpdater[P,A], 
    containsType: ProductContainsType[P,A]
): P = updater(product, f)
```

Let's see:

```
scala> strictUpdate(p){ s: String => s.toUpperCase }
res21: &[&[&[String,Int],User],String] = &(&(&(HELLO,123),User(Elwood,25)),BYE)

scala> strictUpdate(p){ s: Symbol => Symbol(s.name.toUpperCase) }
<console>:19: error: Product &[&[&[String,Int],User],String] does not contain type Symbol
              strictUpdate(p){ s: Symbol => Symbol(s.name.toUpperCase) }
```

Comment: How do I write a type for a product that has `A` and something else? Like `val pp: User & Any = p` or similar using your example.

Comment: You cannot write such a type, but you can require an evidence (an implicit value) that a product type has at least one element of a given type. I'm not sure it is of much value anyway, given that in `update` you want to simply ignore elements that are not of type `A`. I guess your intent is to avoid errors where you thought `update` would update at least one element of the product, but it does not because the product has no element of type `A`, then you have to realize that it will only cover part of the possible errors: you might also intend to update two elements but only one has type `A`.

Comment: Is it possible to make this not compile when a product doesn't contain a value to update?

Comment: Yes, as I hinted in my earlier comment it is possible using a type class (see my update). Bu keep in mind that you still have potential errors that cannot be detected: say  you have a product with **two** elements of type `String` and use `strictUpdate` to modify them. If later on you modify one of the `String` element to be of type `Symbol`, it will still gladly compile, only the `Symbol` element won't be updated anymore.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to do it simpler (see my updated question), though now it's impossible to update/read a duplicated type in a product (something I'm okay with).

Answer (score 3):

Not an optimal variant, seems to me @TravisBrown or @MilesSabin can provide more complete answer.

In examples we will use `shapeless 2.2.5`.
So we can represent the necessary type as a `HList` (no arity problem). As it is a `HList` it is possible to apply a `Poly` function:

```
trait A
def aFunc(a: A) = a

trait lowPriority extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[T] = at[T](poly.identity)
}

object polyApplyToTypeA extends lowPriority {
  implicit def caseA = at[A](aFunc(_))
}

list.map(polyApplyToTypeA) //> applies only to type A
```

That was the first approach, using it we should use only special `Poly` functions (it is possible to generate them), actually, that's a problem.

The second approach is to define an own function, which has a bit difficult logic:

```
def applyToType[L <: HList, P <: HList, PO <: HList, S <: HList, F]
(fun: F => F, l: L)
(implicit partition: Partition.Aux[L, F, P, S],
                 tt: ToTraversable.Aux[P, List, F],
                 ft: FromTraversable[P],
                  p: Prepend.Aux[S, P, PO],
                  a: Align[PO, L]): L = 
(l.filterNot[F] ::: l.filter[F].toList[F].map(fun).toHList[P].get).align[L]
```

This function filters `HList` by a type, converts it to a `List`, applies our function, and converts it back to `HList`, also aligns types, in order not to change `HList` type alignment. Works as expected. Full example here: https://gist.github.com/pomadchin/bf46e21cb180c2a81664

Comment: The second approach is quite interesting (+1). Would it be possible to generalise to a function `f: F => A`? Then in some cases a standard monomorphic function would do, without the need for a `Poly`.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple idea you can do something like this:

```
scala> case class And[A, B](first: A, second: B)
defined class And

scala> val x:  String And Double And Int = And(And("test", 1.1), 10)
x: And[And[String,Double],Int] = And(And(test,1.1),10)

scala> x.copy(second = 100)
res0: And[And[String,Double],Int] = And(And(test,1.1),100)
```

Of course you can define functions with such products:

```
def update(product: String And Int, f: String => String): String And Int
```