# How to Monadic Logging in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

I often want to log or to print something without changing it.

It looks like this:

```
val result = myResult // this could be an Option or a Future
      .map{r =>
        info(s"the result is $r")
        r
      }
```

These three lines are always the same.

In a for comprehension, this can be done a bit nicer.

But I look for a solution for the first declarative version. It should look like:

```
val result = myResult
      .log(info(s"the result is ${_}"))
```

This one-liner could be put in every place in the chain where there could be a map, like:

```
val result = myResult
      .log(info(s"1. ${_}"))
      .filter(_ > 1)
      .log(info(s"2. ${_}"))
      ...
```

How could this be achieved? If possible, without a functional library.

Comment: interesting... Maybe you can define a implicit class that has a method "log" acting on a Product ?

Comment: This can be done using [.flatTap()](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Monad.html#flatTap[A,B](fa:F[A])(f:A=>F[B]):F[A]) when using cats.

Comment: @Marth I don't think `flatTap` is good for chaining as OP shows in the last example

Comment: I was going to suggest the new (Scala 2.13) `tapEach()` but it isn't available on a `Future`. I wonder why. Maybe in the next release?

Comment: @jwvh certainly curious on why Futures are being treated differently. Gonna take this to /contributors see if anyone has an explanation

Comment: @jwvh thanks for the idea. I tried `tapEach()`. It is only implemented in `Iterable`. Using it with `Option` returns a `List`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I decided to take a swing at this and I would like to retract my comment of

> Maybe you can define a implicit class that has a method "log" acting on a Product ?

I was confident that Future and all the monads (collections, options) shared a common ancestor, turns out I was wrong. I have the following solution without using Cats. This can be done in a much prettier way in cats, besides the aforementioned "*flatTap*", and embelished with possibly cats.Ref or something.

Future is the obvious outliner here but as more exceptions come along you might need to expand this object.

```
import scala.concurrent._ 
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object MonadicConv { 
  implicit class MonadicLog[+B <: Product, A] (val u: B){
    def log(l: String, args: List[A] = List()): B = {
      println("logging")
      println(u)
      println(l)
      u
    }  
  }



 implicit class FutureLog[T, A](val u: Future[T]){
    def log(l: String, args: List[A] = List()) : Future[T] = {
      println("logging")
      println(u)
      println(l)
      u
    }
  }
}
```

1) You will need to modify this with you own logging logic, I am just printing

2) I am not super proud of this as this is no longer a pure function. I am not sure if there is a work around this in Scala **without** using Cats. (There might be)

3) The args can be removed, just added them in case you want to pass in extra info

4) If you really want to combine these, you could try defining your own product, some leads: [Implement product type in Scala with generic update function working on its parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541107/implement-product-type-in-scala-with-generic-update-function-working-on-its-part)

You can use this with

```
  import MonadicConv._


  val x = Some(5).log("").get
  val lx = List(Some(5), Some(10), Some(1)).log("list").flatten.log("x").filter(_ > 1).log("")
  val ff = Future.successful(List(Some(5), Some(10), Some(1))).log("fff").map(_.flatten.filter(_ > 1).log("inner")).log("")
```

This prints out

```
logging
Some(5)
option test
logging
List(Some(5), Some(10), Some(1))
list test
logging
List(5, 10, 1)
flat test
logging
List(5, 10)
filter test
logging
Future(Success(List(Some(5), Some(10), Some(1))))
future test
logging
Future(<not completed>)
incomplete test
logging
List(5, 10)
inner future test
```

Scastie version [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/D7JDY7QeTRCsye9dn4hHXw)

As I have mentioned, this is really the Cats land at this point. This is the best I could come up with in core Scala

Comment: Thanks, I had to add a version for Iterable, as Product only covers Try and Option.

Comment: Yeah. List is a Product but I forgot its a special case. Hopefully once Scala 3 brings union types, we can simplify this further

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, it is best to use treelog. It turns the logging process and values into a Monad of `DescribedComputation` :

```
import treelog.LogTreeSyntaxWithoutAnnotations._
val result: DescribedComputation[YourValueType] = myResult ~> (_.fold("The result is empty")(r => s"The result is $r")
```

And usually to subtract the value from a DescribedComputation, use for comprehension:

```
for {
  res <- result
} {
  doSomethingTo(res)
}
```

See details from https://github.com/lancewalton/treelog

---

The whole example will look like:

```
val compRes = "Logging Result" ~< {
    for {
      r <- myResult ~> (_.fold("The result is empty")(r => s"The result is $r")
    } yield r
  }
}

for (res <- compRes) {
  doSomethingTo(res)
}

logger.info(logging.run.written.shows)
```

The output will look like:

```
2019-11-18 00:00:00,000 INFO Logging Result
  The result is XXX
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference. **ZIO** provides this functionality nicely.

```
  /**
   * Returns an effect that effectfully "peeks" at the success of this effect.
   *
   * {{{
   * readFile("data.json").tap(putStrLn)
   * }}}
   */
  final def tap[R1 <: R, E1 >: E](f: A => ZIO[R1, E1, Any]): ZIO[R1, E1, A] = self.flatMap(new ZIO.TapFn(f))
```

There is even a version for the error case:

```
  /**
   * Returns an effect that effectfully "peeks" at the failure of this effect.
   * {{{
   * readFile("data.json").tapError(logError(_))
   * }}}
   */
  final def tapError[R1 <: R, E1 >: E](f: E => ZIO[R1, E1, Any]): ZIO[R1, E1, A]
```

This makes debugging really easy:

```
   myDangerousZioFunction
      .tapError(e => putStrLn(s"Server Exception: $e"))
      .tap(r => putStrLn(s"Result is $r"))
      ....
```